# How to mock tymondesigns/jwt-auth in Laravel 5?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I just added [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to support token auth, and consequently my test cases are failing because there is no token on the headers parameters. How can I mock (using `Mockery`) a component to bypass this?

**Note:** `$this->be()` doesn't work

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I read through the whole source code, and mocked every method call from jwtauth. But it seems Laravel 5.1 has a trait to bypass middlewares, you might wanna check it out

Comment: I'm also very interested in a solution for this. Have tried disabling middleware but can't make it work. Did you solve this? @ChristopherFrancisco

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An **alternative** is to authenticate the request during test execution passing a particular user. This is how did it:

```php
# tests/TestCase.php

/**
 * Return request headers needed to interact with the API.
 *
 * @return Array array of headers.
 */
protected function headers($user = null)
{
    $headers = ['Accept' => 'application/json'];

    if (!is_null($user)) {
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
        JWTAuth::setToken($token);
        $headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '.$token;
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

Then in my tests I use it like this:

```php
# tests/StuffTest.php

/**
 * Test: GET /api/stuff.
 */
public function testIndex()
{
    $url = '/api/stuff';

    // Test unauthenticated access.
    $this->get($url, $this->headers())
         ->assertResponseStatus(400);

    // Test authenticated access.
    $this->get($url, $this->headers(User::first()))
         ->seeJson()
         ->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Hope this help you all. Happy coding!